# Dxdiag result about CPU

Tags: windows, cpu, windows-server-2012

My customer sent me dxdiag result in txt file. For the processor section it says `Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2650 v3 @ 2.30GHz (20 CPUs)`
The "20 CPUs" in parenthesis confused me. This CPU has 10 cores. Does it mean this server has 2 CPUs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The processor is hyper-threaded.  Hyper-threads are not separate cores but instead allow a single core to run two threads simultaneously.  It does not give the full performance of a dedicated core but instead uses the resources of a single core more efficiently.  Hyper-threads are counted as a "core" by Windows though - that is why you're seeing "20."

See the Intel data sheet on that processor: [Here](http://ark.intel.com/products/81705/Intel-Xeon-Processor-E5-2650-v3-25M-Cache-2_30-GHz).  Notice the # of threads.

Comment: Then this is 1 CPU, 10cores, right? If this server had 2 CPUs what would I see in system info?

Comment: Yes, 1 CPU 10 cores, 20 threads.  The number of sockets for multiple CPU's however is separate and a processor must also support multiple sockets.

Comment: @Oktay If you had 2 CPU's each with 10 cores and 20 threads then if you had two of them it would simply be 20 cores with 40 threads.